# Set value of multiple Excel cells to 0 with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, cell, openpyxl

I'm got into programming because of the tasks I do at work, so I'm more of a beginner and not very familiar with programming things. (I have some basic knowledge)

My problem:
In Excel [A1:D1] should be 0 (or any other cells, it's an example)

My idea:

```
x = 97
position = chr(x) + str("1")
while x < 100:
   x +=1
   sheet[position].value = 0
   position = chr(x) + str("1")
```

Something like this, so I would loop until all the cells were reached.
BUT is there an easier solution to this? I mean, that can't be the best way to do it. I imagine something more like:

```
sheet['A1':'D1'].value = 0
```

But then I get a tuple and can't assigne a value.
I searched on SO and YouTube but it seems like nobody had talked about this problem yet.
I really hope somebody can help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the info provided, you are trying to open an Excel file using python openpyxl and update cells A1:D1 (in say Sheet1) with 0s. If that is the case, you can use this. Note that `cell(row, column)` will indicate the particular cell in excel

```
file = openpyxl.load_workbook("Myfile.xlsx",read_only=False)
mySheet = file["Sheet1"]
for col in range(1,5):
    mySheet.cell(1,col).value = 0
file.save("Myfile.xlsx")
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In my actual file, I had to do it for [C4:G4] and it took me a few tries to understand how to locate the right cell to start with, but now I got it. I'm sure this method will help me with future tasks aswell. Big Thank you!